# How to log simpletest test results into files using drush test-run?

Tags: 7, drush, testing

I would like to save simpletest test results into a log file. What bash commands should I use ?

I tried this command (example) but nothing is saved into /var/tmp folder :

```
sudo -u apache drush test-run Comment --xml /var/tmp
```

I use Linux , Drupal 7.12, Drush 4.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use drush test-run, but Drush options are always in the form `--xml=/var/tmp`.

c.f. http://drupal.org/node/1416198

From `drush help test-run`

```
 --xml      Output verbose test results to a     
            specified directory using the JUnit  
            test reporting format. Useful for    
            integrating with Jenkins.
```

Try:

```
sudo -u apache drush test-run Comment --all --xml=/var/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
sudo -u apache drush test-run > /var/tmp/whatever.txt
```

Comment: I tried this as well but unfortunately this also didn't work.

Comment: Actually what I did was just this: drush test-run > /var/tmp/whatever.txt ... What is the error you get?

Comment: if I use your example nothing goes into whatever.txt

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me finally was:

```
sudo -u apache drush test-run Comment --xml=/var/tmp >/var/tmp/test.log 2>/var/tmp/test.err
```

Thanks for help from [hiphip](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/5402/hiphip) and [greg_1_anderson](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2618/greg-1-anderson) :)